# MultiSelect List Box Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that I want to run a query through using a mulitSelect list box. I think I might have it but the SQL section is what is giving me problems. 
Table is "SupervisorsQuery"
Query is "Query1"
List Box is "lstUser"
The query is run through the click event of the button. The error look to start at the FROM Statement. Any help would be great!!

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
Dim Q As QueryDef, DB As Database
Dim Criteria As String
Dim ctl As Control
Dim itm As Variant

Set ctl = Me![lstUser]
For Each itm In ctl.ItemsSelected
    If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
        Criteria = Chr(34) & ctl.ItemData(itm) & Chr(34)
    Else
        Criteria = Criteria & "," & Chr(34) & ctl.ItemData(itm) & Chr(34)
    End If
Next itm
If Len(Criteria) = 0 Then
    itm = MsgBox("You must select one or more items in the list box")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set DB = CurrentDb()
Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("Query1")
Q.SQL = "Select SupervisorsQuery.Date, SupervisorsQuery.Client,SupervisorsQuery.[Job Code Description], SupervisorsQuery.[Perf Percent]"
FROM SupervisorsQuery
WHERE ((SupervisorsQuery.[User ID]) In (" & Criteria & "));"

Q.Close
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"


End Sub
```

Comment: The SQL String in the posted code is only the first line. Is this a typo? You need to add the FROM part to the String either by appending it at the end of the line.

Comment: `Debug.print` your SQL statement. You will see your error quickly. Hint: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Q.SQL = "Select SupervisorsQuery.[Date], SupervisorsQuery.Client,SupervisorsQuery.[Job Code Description], SupervisorsQuery.[Perf Percent] " & _
"FROM SupervisorsQuery " & _
"WHERE ((SupervisorsQuery.[User ID]) In (" & Criteria & "));"
```

Comment: Thank you a million times over. This worked perfectly.